# Blender 2.8 Texture Paint not Painting

Tags: uv, texture-painting

I am still a novice in Blender and was following BlenderMania's Blender tutorial here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ahx15oEvv5g.

When it came to the texture painting part I cannot seem to get it working.Nothing I do seems to get applied in any way. Could somebody help me figure this out?

[image]

Comment: Hi, the problem with paint is not working is usually because there is texture missing. Not sure tho. Post your file for better inspection.

Comment: Have you applied the texture image to the object? You can also try changing the Blend mode of the brush to *Draw*.\